# Serverless framework Variable dependency failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to run a bash script that calls the serverless framework's deploy command, to create AWS resources,
The deploy command passes parameters, which are to be referred to in the serverless.yaml file
My command is like - `serverless deploy --param=deploymentRegion=us-east-1`
While in the serverless.yaml, I am trying to use the passed parameter like -
`region: ${param:deploymentRegion}`

I am getting the following error -

```
Exception -----------------------------------------------
 
  "Variable dependency failure: variable 'param:deploymentRegion' references Serverless Parameters but using that service requires a concrete value to be called."
 
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              16.16.0
     Framework Version:         1.54.0
     Plugin Version:            3.1.2
     SDK Version:               2.1.2
     Components Core Version:   1.1.1
     Components CLI Version:    1.4.0
```

I am trying to refer -
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/parameters

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well, the error message seems pretty self-explanatory, the region field requires a concrete value to be passed and not a parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in your case is that you're using a heavily outdated version of the Framework. The `param`s functionality was introduced in `v3` release, and you're on `v1.54.0` which is no longer supported. Upgrading should do the trick, but you need to be careful and first upgrade to `v2` and then to `v3`.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a shot in the dark, but according to the documentation you shared the expected call should be:

```
serverless deploy --param="deploymentRegion=us-east-1"
```

Note the additional " around the param provided

Comment: yea I tried to add the string around the key value, but getting the same error